# subclass or Inheritance which way is best using hibernate hbm?

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, hbm

Can someone share me the better approach for this below question using hibernate hbm files?

Let's say I have 2 classes called Vehicle, Car and 2 tables Vehicles and Car. Vehicles having generic fields which suppose to have for every Car, Bus, etc.

I am trying to create DomainObject for Car:

1. Car extends Vehicle ? If so, can someone share me how to declare Vehicle class within Car hbm files and both the data get saved when Car object get saved ?
2. I can have 2 hbm separate files (car, vehicle) and in Car class I can declare class (private Vehicle vehicle) and construct this object as a part of Car class and save the Car class using cascade.

Can someone suggest which approach will be good ? I need to store the data in both the tables.

Comment: Subclass(ing) and Inheritance are the same :)

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using? Also, I would recommend switching to JPA or JPA2 with Hibernate as a provider. It makes tasks like this (even more) trivial.

Comment: gubs: It's been a week.  You only got one answer, so please either select my answer, or clarify your question so you'll get other answers.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between using one table or two is largely preference, but I would factor in:

- Whether you'll ever want to query all vehicles of any type
- How many attributes will be common (inherited) to all vehicle types
- How many vehicles you're talking about (if there are a lot, a separate table might be faster)

If you do want to do it with one table, then you can use a discriminator field ([as described in this page](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t18300.html)) to identify which subclass a record is. [Here's the Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperclass).

Comment: ,Whether you'll ever want to query all vehicles of any type
[Reply] : Nope
How many attributes will be common (inherited) to all vehicle types
[Reply] : 44 fields
How many vehicles you're talking about (if there are a lot, a separate table might be faster
[Reply] : 5 types